# Particle object cutting through mesh on which I am currently weight painting

Tags: particles

I am weight painting particles on mesh, and instead of them be on surface, they are cutting through. How can I make it to be just on surface[image]

Comment: put the origin of your particle object on its bottom face

Comment: Wow. That's it. I thought it is already there but forgot to check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the origin of your particle object on its bottom face. The particle origin will stick to the emitter surface.